# I can not Resume the CameraActivity in Android?

Tags: java, android

I am working on an App that use camera for face recognition. But i have some problem when i resume my app the the app always crash.
This is my code Onresume Activity:

```java
@Override
  public synchronized void onResume() {
//    LOGGER.d("onResume " + this);
    super.onResume();;
    handlerThread = new HandlerThread("inference");
    handlerThread.start();
    handler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper());

  }
```

This is my code in CameraActivity:

[CameraActivity.java](https://gist.github.com/seabnavin19/479cda227baa1d37e3876296c394a448#file-cameraactivity-java)

And this is the class that i used for recognize the face that extends from cameraActivity:
[Detector Activity](https://gist.github.com/seabnavin19/479cda227baa1d37e3)

This is The error that I got:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.samples.flironecamera, PID: 23171
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.samples.flironecamera/com.samples.flironecamera.DetectorActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.hardware.Camera.startPreview()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4644)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4677)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:52)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
```

Comment: Instead of posting picture of the error and link of your Github account for the code, please copy-paste the error as well as your code in your question

Comment: hello i already update. for the code it is too large.